# How to access non locals variables (lazy format)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do something like this (Python 3.8.x!):

```py
import inspect

class LazyFStr(str):
    _template = ''
    def __init__(self, s):
        self._template = s
    def __repr__(self):
        vs = inspect.getclosurevars(lambda: True) #self.__repr__)
        print(vs)
        return self._template.format(**vs.nonlocals)
```

and when I call it in the REPL snippet like:

```py
>>> x = 123
>>> s = LazyFStr('aaa {x} bbb')
>>> s
```

I get:

```
ClosureVars(nonlocals={}, globals={}, builtins={}, unbound=set())
...
KeyError: 'x'
```

which means that I cannot access the variable `x`. How to achieve this?

Comment: `inspect.getclosurevars` returns the names of each type that the passed function is USING.  Your lambda uses no variables, so they all return empty.

Comment: oh, it seems to be true, 10x